# Apex test class for REST service

Tags: apex

I have written a APEX REST service that I have exposed. The service works great. However I am struggling to write the test class for this. Here is my APEX Rest Web Service:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/getStores/*')
global class StoresService {

    @HttpGet
    global static List<Stores> StoresInfo() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

        Double latitude = Decimal.valueOf(RestContext.request.params.get('latitude'));
        Integer distance = Integer.valueOf(RestContext.request.params.get('distance'));

        Stores st = new Stores();
        List<Account> storesList = new List<Account>();
        List<Stores> objList = new List<Stores>();

        if (latitude <> null && latitude <> 0 ) {
            storesList = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, 
                              DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:latitude,-127), 'mi') dist FROM Account 
                              WHERE DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:latitude,-127), 'mi') <60

                              ORDER BY DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:latitude,:longitude), 'mi') ASC
                              LIMIT 10];  

        } else {

            st.errorCode = 'No stores found ';
        }

        for(Account a : storesList){
            st = new Stores();
            st.name = a.Name;
            st.Phone = a.Phone;


            objList.add(st);

        }

        return objList;


    }



       global class Stores {
            public String name;
            public Location location;
            public String Phone;

        }

        public class Location {
            public Decimal lat;
            public Decimal lng;
         }

    }



This is my attempt to the test class but it has several errors which I have marked:
    @isTest
    public class StoresTest {
        static testMethod void testStoresService(){

            Account acc=new Account();
   acc.name='Test';
   acc.AccountNumber='1232332'; 
                insert acc;
                System.AssertNotEquals(null,acc.Id);

                //Start the test execution
                Test.startTest();       

                RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
                RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
                req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/getStores';

                req.addParameter('latitude', String.valueOf(acc.BillingLatitude));
                req.addParameter('distance', String.valueOf(10));
                req.httpMethod = 'GET';
                RestContext.request = req;
                RestContext.response = res;        
                StoresService.Stores reqst = new StoresService.StoresInfo();   //Says invalid type

                //Assert we got the correct data back
                System.assertEquals(acc.Phone, reqst.Phone); //this always fails assertion because the actual value is null

                //Stop the test execution
                Test.stopTest();

            }
        }  


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the declaration

```
global static List<Stores> StoresInfo() {
```

It is 1st `static` and 2nd returning a `List<Stores>`, so your

```
StoresService.Stores reqst = new StoresService.StoresInfo();
```

should actually be

```
List<StoresService.Stores> reqst = StoresService.StoresInfo();
```

then of course you would have to change

```
System.assertEquals(acc.Phone, reqst.Phone);
```

by the following, because it is no longer a record, but a list

```
System.assertEquals(1, reqst.size());
System.assertEquals(acc.Phone, reqst.get(0).Phone);
```

Comment: Actually tried that line, but when I did that I kept on getting variable does not exist "Phone" in the line where I am doing the assert statement. So its saying reqst.Phone doesnt exist

Comment: @user3688231 Edit done to fix the next line

Comment: Its giving List index out of bounds on that line

Comment: @user3688231 I'm assuming you did not put the assert of the size()... Your code is not giving the correct data and/or your query not filtering properly. Analyse what is the business requirement and adjust them accordingly. I don't see you setting the longitude or latitude to the account anywhere (to give you an example), so most likely your webservice is giving you `No stores found `